# Is it possible to completely not see "not interested" flagged questions?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, ignored-tags

Right now when a tag is flagged as not interested it appears faded and greyed out.

I like this behaviour normally. However with certain new games such as Fallout 4 I do not want to know anything about the game so as to have that wonderful self discovery experience.

Is there anything more I can do, besides not visiting arqade for the next month, to block out these questions until I am ready to see them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, that is an option.

Select "Edit" beside Favorite Tags, then Set Tag Preferences (or simply go to https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/current).  Go down to Ignored Tags and select the "Hide questions in your ignored tags" radio button.

[image]

Comment: Oh, that is just perfect. Thanks!